Why can't backend receive the arguments sent by the frontend
The frontend sends data in JSON format, but the backend receives empty data.
this is the data frontend send.
{
  "user": {
    "id": 0,
    "imgUrl": "default.jpg",
    "userName": "d",
    "password": "d",
    "email": "ddd@dd.com"
  },
  "verification": "d"
}

this is the data what received by the backend.
This is a screenshot of Debug in IDEA, the user and verification in the figure are expected to get data from the frontend, but Debug finds that their values are null.
The User class is defined as follows
package com.example.back.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Integer id;
    private String imgUrl;
    public User(String name,String password,String email){
        this.userName=name;
        this.password=password;
        this.email=email;
    }
}

Next is the code in which the problem occurred.
@PostMapping("/signin")
public Message signIn( User user, String verification) {
     if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(redisTemplate.hasKey(user.getEmail())) && Boolean.TRUE.equals(redisTemplate.hasKey(verification))) {
         if (redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(user.getEmail()) == verification) {
             try {
                 userMapper.insert(user);
             } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
                 return Message.error("用户已注册");
             }
             user = userMapper.getByEmail(user.getEmail());
             String token = JWTUtils.generToken(user.getId());
             return Message.success("注册成功", token);
         }
     }
     return Message.error("验证码错误");
 }

I've tried adding @RequestParam to the two parameters separately to fix this, but without success.

There are 2 errors:

You are missing @RequestBody.
In the json user and verification are part of another object - the json does not match what you parse it to in the backend.

public class SignIn {

  private User user;
  private String verification;

  //getters and setters
}

In the handler method:
@PostMapping("/signin")
public Message signIn(@RequestBody SignIn signIn) {
  ...
}


Is it really an efficient and maintainable way to create a single class for each interface?

@sleepawhile I don't really understand your question. The format of what you send from the frontend and the object you receive at the backend must match, no way around that. If you don't want to create a class, then you must deserialize into the generic match every object - Map<String, Object>, which is actually the unmaintainable way.
